# Why bacteria produce light?

Tags: molecular-biology, microbiology, bacteriology, bioluminescence

After seeing [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=saWSxLU0ME8) video I am curious to know why the free living bacteria produce light. What advantage will they have ? Or is it just an "unintentional" result of one of their pathways ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go for the  link below, you will find an article on "How do marine bacteria produce light, why are they luminescent, and can we employ bacterial bioluminescence in aquatic biotechnology?"

[www.biology-online.org/articles/marine_bacteria_produce_light/abstract.html](http://www.biology-online.org/articles/marine_bacteria_produce_light/bacteria_emit_light.html)

From this article :

> The question remains whether quorum sensing regulation of bacterial
>   luminescence is a kind of a ‘social behaviour’ in which cells
>   ‘predict’ the possibility of increased mutagenesis where conditions
>   allow for efficient metabolism leading to extensive bacterial growth.
>   Such conditions may cause the appearance of large quantities of
>   metabolites, including mutagenic agents. Thus, one could speculate
>   that enhanced light emission at a high cell density may ensure more
>   efficient DNA repair in response to potentially increased
>   concentrations of mutagens. Alternatively, quorum sensing may be
>   needed for another role of bacterial bioluminescence, besides
>   stimulation of photoreactivation.